# CCScrollView doesn't show ContentNode

Tags: spritebuilder, cocos2d-swift

I succeeded to show a contentNode on a scrollView published from SpriteBuilder. But couldn't  show it on a scrollView made programatically.

I just put these codes on didLordFromCCB MainScene.m. I did nothing with the SpriteBuilder project.

```
CCNodeColor* base = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor blueColor] width:760 height:200];
base.position = ccp(30, 200);
CCNodeColor* color0 = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor magentaColor] width:100 height:100];
color0.position= ccp(0, 0);
[base addChild:color0];

CCNodeColor* color1 = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor magentaColor] width:100 height:100];
color1.position= ccp(660, 0);
[base addChild:color1];

CCNodeColor* color2 = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor magentaColor] width:100 height:100];
color2.position= ccp(330, 100);
[base addChild:color2];

CCScrollView* sv = [[CCScrollView alloc]initWithContentNode:base];
[self addChild:sv];

sv.horizontalScrollEnabled = YES;
sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(260, 200);
[sv setPositionInPoints:ccp(30, 200)];
```

Comment: try to put that logic in onEnter instead, where the parent node's content size is certain to be set.

Comment: Thank you. 

I put these codes within onEnter method but scrollView didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm late but maybe I still can help someone:

Inside of CCScrollView initialisation I found this line:

```
self.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeNormalized;
```

So you just need to set contentSizeType back to "CCSizeTypePoints":

```
sv.contentSize = CCSizeTypePoints;
sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(260, 200);
```

Hope this helps!
I signed up a few mins ago just to leave this comment :)

Comment: good answers are never too late to be provided to this community. stackoverflow does not evaluate grave digging as something bad if it helps people that might find a solution in your answer.